# How can I remove the pasue between these animation steps?

Tags: css, css-animations

In the animation in this example I have the middle circle rorating upwards then coming back down.
You can see that after it finishes spinning at 95% height, there's a small break before it moves to the next animation step where it no longer spins, but moves to 100% height.

I would like to eliminate the break that happens between the 70% and 87% steps of the animation.
In other words: I want the circle to stop spinning and continue moving upwards without stopping.
How can I do that?

```css
:root {
  --final-rotation: calc(360deg * 5);
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.word {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #52b87f;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 25%;
  padding-right: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.letter {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation: bounce-o 2s;
}

@keyframes bounce-o {
  0% {
    scale: 0;
  }
  
  70% {
    scale: 2;
    transform: translateY(-85%) rotate(var(--final-rotation));
  }
  
  87% {
    scale: 2;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(var(--final-rotation));
  }  
  
  95% {
    scale: 2;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(var(--final-rotation));
  }
  
  100% {
    scale: 1;
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(var(--final-rotation));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="word">
<svg height="100" width="100" class="letter">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Linear Timing Function

The current animation is  set with `animation: bounce-o 2s;`.
Implicitly this will set a timing function of `ease`.
When the animation runs, it will ease into each step (every % rule). This is where the 'break' comes from.

During the first portion (0 to 70%), the ease function will animate fast at the first half of that animation step (so the 0 to 35% portion) and then slow down at the end portion of that step animation (from about 35% to 70%). coming to full halt at 70%. Then starting at full speed for to the next step.

You could try a linear timing function.
this will have a consistent speed for the entire animation.
For [comparison](https://cubic-bezier.com/#1,1,0,0)
set it like this:
`animation: bounce-o 2s linear;`

```css
:root {
  --final-rotation: calc(360deg * 5);
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.word {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #52b87f;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 25%;
  padding-right: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.letter {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation: bounce-o 2s linear;
}

.snippit-wrapper {
  transform: translate(0, 70%);
}

@keyframes bounce-o {
  0% {
    scale: 0;
  }
  70% {
    scale: 2;
    transform: translateY(-85%) rotate(calc(1 * var(--final-rotation)));
  }
  87% {
    scale: 2;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(var(--final-rotation));
  }
  95% {
    scale: 2;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(var(--final-rotation));
  }
  100% {
    scale: 1;
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(var(--final-rotation));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="snippit-wrapper">
  <div class="word">
    <svg height="100" width="100" class="letter">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Break It Up

If you prefer to keep the easing timing, you could add a wrapper and animate the y translation solely on the wrapper, while animating the spin solely on the child.

You would define separate animations for both.

```css
:root {
  --final-rotation: calc(360deg * 5);
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.word {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #52b87f;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 25%;
  padding-right: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.letter {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation: bounce-o-spin 2s;
}

.wrapper {
  animation: bounce-o-translate 2s;
}

.snippit-wrapper {
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
}

@keyframes bounce-o-spin {
  0% {
    scale: 0;
  }
  70% {
    scale: 2;
    transform: rotate(calc(1 * var(--final-rotation)));
  }
  87% {
    scale: 2;
    transform: rotate(var(--final-rotation));
  }
  95% {
    scale: 2;
    transform: rotate(var(--final-rotation));
  }
  100% {
    scale: 1;
    transform: rotate(var(--final-rotation));
  }
}

@keyframes bounce-o-translate {
  0% {}
  95% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="snippit-wrapper">
  <div class="word">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <svg height="100" width="100" class="letter">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```